# What is the best way to detect collisions in an infinite scroll 2D game?

Tags: java, android, collision

I am developing an android 2D game which involves infinite running and jumping to great heights. I am trying to implement a modified hash grid that recycles its cells, but the more i dig into it the more i feel it's going to be very slow. I also use the hash grid to have a reference on what to render and spawn. My question is, are there any systems that satisfy my needs? Or perhaps some tips to use the grid efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look to [Box2D](http://box2d.org/)
I had to take care of a game with some collisions in the past, but it was in Java so I could work perfectly with awt.geom library, which is not available in Android.

Another approach would be to work with [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) and detecting collisions with "contains" and "intersect".